# WebRequest to Sharepoint site using Access Token returns 403

Tags: csom, authorization, 403, token

I need to create web request to specific page in SharePoint Online using Access Token in order to get certain Header information, but I keep getting 403 and I'm not sure why. After toying with access requests some more, I managed to only get 403 using clientContext, and 401 using Postman.

I can get response from grah api in my app and with postman using access token, but the problem is I need to do a web request to get real web page headers like SpRequestDuration and SPIISLatency.

1. I've followed steps to create my Azure AD and application.
2. I request user login to get authentication code for my application

   ```
   loginScopes = [
   'User.Read.All',
   'Directory.Read.All',
   'Group.Read.All',
   'Sites.Read.All',
   'Reports.Read.All' 
   'offline_access',
   'https://www.sharepoint.com/AllSites.FullControl'
   ];

   const encodedScopes = encodeURIComponent(loginScopes.join(' '));
   const encodedRedirectUri = encodeURIComponent(redirectUri);
   let url = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
   response_type=code&
   client_id=${clientId}
   &redirect_uri=${encodedRedirectUri}
   &scope=${encodedScopes}
   &prompt=select_account`;

   return url;
   ```

After this returns authentication code I create ConfidentialClientApplication with authority : 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations' and with my application clientId, secret, redirect etc.
With newly created ConfidentialClientApplication I acquire token silently with scope '{tenantUrl}/AllSites.FullControl' and user from token cache.

Now with access token I successfully create ClientContext, which retrieves data from sharepoint site and I can easily make a graph API request and everything will be fine. But the problem is with creating a WebRequest to a specific site (example. {tenantUrl}/SitePages/Forms/ByAuthor.aspx)

```
var manager = new AuthenticationManager();
var clientContext = manager.GetAzureADAccessTokenAuthenticatedContext(tenantUrl, accessToken);
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Site);
clientContext.Load(oWebsite.Lists);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); // Works fine

var request = clientContext.WebRequestExecutorFactory.CreateWebRequestExecutor(clientContext,{tenantUrl}/SitePages/Forms/ByAuthor.aspx).WebRequest;

request.Method = "GET";
//request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");

clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += delegate (object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
{
    e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
};
await request.GetResponseAsync(); // Throws 403
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steve mentioned, it is not possible to get request from site using access token. We managed to solve the problem by fetching and using FedAuth and rtFa cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same [problem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/248732/how-to-get-cookies-after-obtaining-azure-ad-access-token-to-sharepoint-online/248735). It seems you cannot access anything outside of a Microsoft API with an access token.